# get the innerhtml inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tree

The html code is pasted into this url http://jsfiddle.net/nzYjV/

The div (id="input") contains the string of alphabet..
Between the "input" div and "d1" div, there are 34 character (including space).
Inside the "d1" div, there are 16 character (including space)
Finally, between ending of "d1" div and before end tag of "input" tag, there is 9 character (including space).

I have to show limited number of string and add link for viewing whole content e.g.

1)suppose string limit is 30,the output would be

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o ... [a href="#"]view more[/a]
```

and output html would be

```
[div id="input"]a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o [/div]
```

2)But, if the string limit is 40, then the output would be

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t...  [a href="#"]view more[/a]
```

And the output html would be

```
[div id="input"]a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q [div id="d1"] r s t [/div][/div]
```

3) And, if the string limit is 55, then the output would be

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v q x y z a1 b1...  [a href="#"]view more[/a]
```

And the output html would be

```
[div id="input"]a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q [div id="d1"] r s tb u v w x y[/div]z a1 b1[/div]
```

i am able to get the inner text of "input" div and "d1" div. But, i am not able to get the last text "z a1 b1 c1", if the 3rd condition is true.

Sorry for bad editing.. Please help me to solve this

Comment: A tricky way would be: `alert($(this).html().split("</div>")[1]);`. This basically splits the HTML of the div up in two parts (the part before the `</div>` of the nested div and the part after it), then you obtain the second part (index 1). http://jsfiddle.net/nzYjV/

Comment: @pimvdb: Thanks a lot.. Sorry!!! It's my mistake.. In my example, your solution works.. But, i am not sure about the input. it may be a div, span,p or mixup of all element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... using this js file 
https://github.com/tagedieb/jquery-truncate

Another set of truncate..

https://github.com/Poetro/jQuery-Truncate